# add multiple PDF files to wordpress post or page

Tags: php, wordpress, pdf

I need some help with wordpress, I'm not too experienced with it, and I need to add multiple pdf to the post/page edit screen back-end and display then the added files on the front-end to let the user download them. I've found [this article](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Custom_Fields_to_attach_images,_links_or_files_to_a_post_easily) but I'm not sure if this is the way to follow, I will not know the labels and I'm not sure if inside a custom metabox is possible to create dynamic fields (add more fields like label and file if needed). I don't want to use a bloated plugin, how I can proceed?

Comment: I would guess that this question would be suited better at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com. But I might be wrong.

Comment: @Twonky I've asked there but the "wordpresser" as I like to define the wordpress developers, are suggesting to use a plugin, and this seems to be the only solution they know for almost all the coding challenges they will afford.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is upload the PDF using the media uploader and then linking them in the frontend while creating a post.

A simple sample at - https://www.wpmadesimple.org/supplementary-guides/adding-pdf-documents/

Let me know if you need more help. This is without a plugin, though there might be more solutions like CPT/Plugins but that is based on your needs.

Comment: I will take a look to the link, thanks. What I need is a solution that can be managed by the client simply by adding a file in a custom metabox for a specific cpt or page and then display it with a predefined template that will be a simple paged list of the files

Comment: There are two way to achieve this. Either write a custom meta field box or use ACF (https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/). A preferred way is using ACF, very helpful, light and not bloated. Also could help in future custom developments.